# Como renderizar nome ou razão social de acordo com o tipo

Tags: java, rich-faces

Estou tentando renderizar o conteúdo de uma coluna de uma tabela com nome ou razão Social dependendo do tipo

```
<f:facet name="header"> #{contato.tipoCadastro.codigo eq '1' ? 'Nome' : 'Razão Social/Nome Fantasia'}</f:facet>
```

O codigo é do tipo String.

Ocorre que sempre renderiza Razão Social/Nome Fantasia.

Answer (score -1):

Existe uma solução mais elegante para isso, que seria resolvida em sua modelagem através de herança/polimorfismo, você poderia modelar uma classe super, por exemplo a classe Pessoa, tendo como subclasses (herança) `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica`, na superclasse você poderia ter o método `getNomeFormatado`, ou `getDescricao` por exemplo, retornando o texto correto, devidamente formatado para clada objeto pelo tipo... esse é o conceito de polimorfismo.

```
Pessoa p1 = new PessoaFisica(); // retorna em getNomeFormatado() o valor de getNome().
Pessoa p2 = new PessoaJuridica(); // retorna o valor de getNomeFormatado() o valor de getRazaoSocial().
```

Sem ifs, sem gambiarras, somente boa modelagem, um bom design da aplicação. Uma outra opção menos elegante, porém que funcionaria perfeitamente seria ter um método `getNomeFormatado()` sem herança ou polimorfismo que verificasse dentro do método:

```
contato.tipoCadastro.codigo == '1' ? contato.getNome() : contato.getRazaoSocial();
```

Espero ter ajudado.